# Extracting inode from ls command

Tags: linux, unix, pattern-matching

I am trying to extract inode from ls command:

```
 "ls -i"
```

out put:

```
1234 File name with space
2345 File name
```

In order to extract, I tried to use cut command as follows:

```
ls -i | cut -d" " -f1
```

above command didn't work cuz the files name have different number of spaces in them. From man page I found that by specifying "-Q" to ls command, it would double quote the file name:

```
ls -iQ 
1234 "File name with space"
2345 "File name"
```

I can't find a way on to utilize this option. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

**Update 1**
It looks like the file name space wasn't the cause of the problem. It's the inode number size. For example:

```
ls -iQ
2321352 "My Cheat Tables"
 507896 "My Data Sources"
```

Note the leading space before the number " 507896". Therefore, for the first file, the inode is in field 1(-f1) and for the second file inode number is on the second field (-f2).

**Updat 2 (My solution)**

I found the solution.. xD the command as follows:

```
ls -iQ | cut -d ' "' -f1
```

above would print inode only. However, I would like to know if there is proper or better way of doing this. Please do answer on this post if you know the right way. I am new to unix, and I would love to learn it in the proper way. Thanks.. :)

Comment: *"above command didn't work cuz the files name have different number of spaces in them"* - so you also need the file names? you can run `cut ... -f1` and `cut ... -f2-` to get the rest of the columns

Comment: I do not need the file name, only need the inode. It's the trailing space before the inode causing the problem. I updated the post, please take a look. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use the [stat(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stat.1.html) command.

```
stat -c %i "File name with spaces"
```

Comment: This is much better solution. Just wondering if stat command is available across all platform! is it??

Comment: `stat` is part of *coreutils* so should be available on all Linux systems.

Answer (score 2):

if you have an unknown number of trailing (or delimiting) white spaces, you can use `awk` to get the desired column:

```
ls -iQ1 | awk '{print $1}'
```

other than `cut`, `awk` ignores any number of consecutive white spaces so you don't need to guess the offset.

an even better solution is to ask explicitly for the information you need rather than parse `ls` output:

```
find . -type f -printf '%i\n'
```

Comment: Ahhh, I guess this would be the better way than my solution. Can you tell me what is "1" in ur "ls -iQ1" command does??

Comment: sometimes, if your terminal window is large enough, ls will print the output in two or more columns. `ls -1` puts files in one column

Comment: ughh gotcha..! I surely do have a long way to go in unix.. :D but thanks for your solutions and explanations, appreciate it. Have a good one.. :)